# FFmpeg noob: Crop and stack video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am looking for a video solution for a 360 video that gives clips in panoramic strips.

I want to crop / split a video and stack it.

After a long morning, I managed to install Homebrew and FFmpeg successfully (although I don't know how I did it). I also managed to crop the video and stack it, but in 3 steps.

```
ffmpeg -i /Users/xx/desktop/Test360.mp4 -filter:v crop=1920:640:0:0 Out.mp4


ffmpeg -i /Users/xx/desktop/Test360.mp4 -filter:v crop=1920:640:1920:0 Out2.mp4


ffmpeg -i /Users/xx/desktop/Out.mp4 -i /Users/xx/desktop/Out2.mp4 -filter_complex vstack=inputs=2 Stacked.mp4
```

Can I collapse this into 1 command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i Test360.mp4 -filter_complex \
                       "split=2[top][bottom];\
                        [top]crop=1920:640:0:0[top];\
                        [bottom]crop=1920:640:1920:0[bottom];\
                        [top][bottom]vstack=2"  stacked.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get:

[AVFilterGraph @ 000002018621c5c0] No such filter: '\'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: Those are to escape line breaks. If entering in one line, remove `\\`.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.